# Regex for parsing Kirby tags

Tags: php, regex, kirby

I am developing a plugin for [Kirby CMS](https://getkirby.com/). It has a data type called kirby tags. I want to parse it.

I have the following input:

```
(link: http://google.com/ nospace:yes text: hello world foo: tesat: baz)
```

From which I extract:

```
link: http://google.com/ nospace:yes text: hello world foo: tesat: baz
```

Then, I need to parse this input and get the following output:

```
array (
  'link' => 'http://google.com/',
  'nospace' => 'yes',
  'text' => 'hello world',
  'foo' => '',
  'tesat' => 'baz',
)
```

I almost have the desired result, but I have trouble with handling empty pairs and values with whitespace. Check my regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/1rEi5U/3):

```
([a-z0-9_-]+):(?:\s?(\S+))?
```

Basically, I need to match the start of the string or some whitespace, then some characters (the key), a colon, and all the rest, until I reach another whitespace + characters combination.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: How to distinguish between `link: http://google.com/` and `foo: tesat: baz` ?

Comment: There should be a space after `:`. In Kirby, it's technically not necessary, but it would be OK if my pattern doesn't catch that. If there's no other way, that would be alright.

Comment: What's about `nospace:yes` ?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov: If at least one space is there after `:` then you may try [`([\w-]+):\h+(.*?(?=\h*(?:\b[\w-]+: |$)))`](https://regex101.com/r/1rEi5U/4)

Comment: ^ If use recursive regex: `(\b[\w-]+:\h+).*?(?=(?1)|$)` - https://regex101.com/r/1rEi5U/5